# What do I do about Oracle .pll files?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I've been brought in to help with an older install of E-Business Suite.  They are still using forms and reports 6i.  I've been given the .rdf files but when I try to access them I get the following error message:

PDE-PLI018 Could not find library (and the name of the report is listed here)

I've read several threads that discuss ensuring your regedit settings are pointed to the .pll files, etc.  First I don't have an entry for oracle in my regedit and second I don't have any .pll files.

Can you help me determine what I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PDE-PLI018 error refers to the name of the PLL, not the report. Perhaps they have named the PLL with the same name as the RDF.

First, you need to get the PLL file from whoever gave you the RDF.

Then, put it in a folder somewhere, and point to that folder in your REPORTS_PATH (where this is varies depending on your OS, e.g. in Windows it's in the registry).

Comment: Thank you, Jeffrey!  I did a reinstall of the client tools and did like normal when you generally used to copy plls from the app server and this install seems to recognize and work fine.  Not sure if I'll be any help but I am at least not getting that error!  I sure appreciate the tip!  Thank you so much!